# How to pin a body in case of collision in Box2D or Farseer?

Tags: physics, box2d, physics-engine, farseer-physics-engine

I'm trying to get an understanding for the Box2D/Farseer physics engine by implementing a small air hockey simulation.
There, I have the problem that the CPU player attacks the puck, kicks it, but also gets kicked back due to restitution.
I would like the CPU player's mallet to be pinned to where it currently is; being able to kick others, but not getting kicked by something else.

I have tried setting its restitution to  0 but restitution is always the maximum of the two colliding bodies and as the puck has a restitution of 0.9, the mallet will also move.

I have also tried changing the mass of the mallet to a insanely high value but this influences damping again.

What is the best approach to really pin it afte collision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried setting its restitution to 0 but restitution is always the maximum of the two colliding bodies and as the puck has a restitution of 0.9, the mallet will also move.

I thought you came to conclusion that this was not true in the comment in another question?

Anyways the only thing I can think of is to use a sensor.

On BeginContact disable the body and set the Body.Position manually to a location beside the mallet. To pass/shoot I would sets its velocity in what ever direction and then re-enable the puck after its a certain radius distance from the player.

Comment: Yeah, I seem to have been wrong about the restitution. It really is using the max. Your idea brought me to the following solution: I added a collision handler. If it collides with the puck, the LinearVelocity is set to 0. This prevents bouncing and stops the mallet. Thanks for the hint with the velocity.